# RSA Encryption via C# privatekey xml access

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, rsa, private-key

I used this article [RSA Encryption in C#](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/692-RSA-Encryption-C.aspx) and it's perfectly working fine ...
But I think there is a security problem .
if we want to use this method,we must put xml files in web root directory and anyone can access these keys...
how can we prevent this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emphasis of the article is about how to use asymmetric encryption (RSA) and an example in C#.  Key management is, really, another (big) topic.

On windows, there are [key containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5cs0acs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) where you can save private keys and then set user permissions on who can read/write/modify the key.

You can then [administer the import and export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the keys in order to move them between machines.

As you point out, key management is vital to design a secure system.  There are many solutions that vary in complexity and cost.